NU1301 Unable to load the service index for source [Visual Studio accessing Azure Artifact package feed]
In VS2022 17.11.0 I am right clicking my solution and selecting Restore Nuget Packages
I then see a dialog asking

"Let's get you signed in" Nuget MyFeedName needs your credentials.

I am logging in with my personal microsoft account. This used to work.
I can see the artifact in DevOps when logged in with this credential
However I now get NU1301 errors for the package when I try to build.
I am able to access
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myentity/_packaging/myFeed/nuget/v3/index.json


I was able to work around this by removing a different login I had to a different Azure subscription.
This was showing under account settings, when I click my initials in the top right of the visual studio title bar.
When I added the correct account here I got an error
Unable To Sign In error 
WAM Error Code:3399942154
WAM Error Message: The internet connection has timed out 
Internal Error Code:557973641

However on the second attemt I was able to add the account.
Now my Nuget restore works

It sounds like cached information from another account was causing the issue. Thanks for sharing your solution!
